# Does NetSuite Advanced PDF Template Support Absolute Positioning?

Tags: html, css, pdf, netsuite

I tried to position my table to the bottom of my PDF page. However, I always got "unexpected error" when I used "position: absolute; bottom: 0px;" to define my table's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://bfo.com/products/report/docs/userguide.pdf (page 24)

> There is one critical condition when using absolutely positioned
>   elements; the element cannot be the child of the BODY element. This is
>   because unlike HTML, elements must be assigned to a page before they
>   can be positioned, but as absolutely positioned items are independent
>   of their siblings, there’s no way to decide which page they go on. To
>   position an item at an absolute position on a specific page, it can be
>   placed in a “background-macro” which is then assigned to the page.

You can use `position: absolute;` but it needs to be in a container `<div>` or `background-macro`.